# Better way to sort double Big Decimal numbers

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

I have list of strings, want to sort the values.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("200.1043725170");
list.add("100.1043725171");
list.add("100.1043725170");
list.add("65535.4294967295");
list.add("4294967295.65535");
```

Tried couple of approaches to sort the same but failed to achieve with efficient solution to get accurate results.

```
list.forEach(value ->{
            dList.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(value)));
        });
        Collections.sort(dList);
```

With the above approach, the values are sorting but the last zero's are not printing after (.) because it's not considered relevant. But I need to have that tailing zeros as well because we are comparing these values in some other place.

The final output I'm looking for is

```
100.1043725170
100.1043725171
200.1043725170
65535.4294967295
4294967295.65535
```

Any suggestions here to achieve the same with efficient approach

Comment: Comparing as String values. dList is just a list "List<BigDecimal> dList = new ArrayList<>();"  -- While returning, I must have to return as list of strings from this API

Comment: What is a 'double `BigDecimal` number'?

Comment: Why do you need padding zero on first and third but not the last one?

Comment: In my input the last element doesn't had the tailing zero. I shouldn't manipulate the input values just want to sort them.

Comment: So you need a single padding zero on 9-digit numbers but you don’t need five padding zeros on a 5-digit number? That makes no sense. You said, « But I need to have that tailing zeros as well because we are comparing these values in some other place. »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave your list as list of Strings sorted by BigDecimal generated from each String element:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new));
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jq55OA).

> [100.1043725170, 100.1043725171, 200.1043725170, 65535.4294967295, 4294967295.65535]

Answer (score 4):

## Update

The best solution is in the [Answer by Sergey Afinogenov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553256/642706), a very brief one-line of code. Below are my two approaches. Not as succinct, but I will leave them here as they may prove interesting to readers.

## Avoid `double`/`Double`

Your code converts your strings into `double` or `Double` values. Doing so introduces the inherent [inaccuracy of floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) technology. Avoid this if you care about accuracy.

Instead, parse your input strings directly as `BigDecimal` objects.

## Regenerate strings after converting to `BigDecimal`

You must parse your strings directly as `BigDecimal`. Collect those objects into a list. Sort. Then generate a new list of fresh `String` objects by generating a new string value for each `BigDecimal`. Each of these steps has been covered many time already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

## `NavigableMap< BigDecimal , String >`

Alternatively, use a `SortedMap`/`NavigableMap`. Map the `BigDecimal` derived from each input string to that string. The keys, being `BigDecimal` objects (which are [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html)), are automatically sorted by mathematical order. Feed the collection produced by a call to `values` into the constructor of a new `List` to get your result.

```java
List < String > list = List.of( "200.1043725170" , "100.1043725171" , "100.1043725170" , "65535.4294967295" , "4294967295.65535" );
NavigableMap < BigDecimal, String > map =
        list
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                ( String s ) -> new BigDecimal( s ) ,
                                Function.identity() ,
                                ( existing , replacement ) -> existing ,   // In case of duplicate key conflict, first one wins.
                                TreeMap :: new
                        )
                );
List < String > result = List.copyOf( map.values() );

System.out.println( result );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/P9R1zl).

> [100.1043725170, 100.1043725171, 200.1043725170, 65535.4294967295, 4294967295.65535]

Comment: @Andy Agreed. So as I said, you have two choices: Recreate the strings, or manage them via a `Map`. I seem to be missing your point?

Comment: @Basil Bourque thanks for edition and interesting alternative solution

Comment: You can simplify `( String s ) -> new BigDecimal( s )` to `BigDecimal::new`. It’s worth noting that this `toMap(…)` approach will eliminate duplicates, unlike the `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new))` of the accepted answer. To retain duplicates (or strings that might be different put parse to the same value), you’d have to use `groupingBy`, to get a list of all strings for each key, followed by streaming and `flatMap`ing over the `values()`.